# Adding color to selected areas in ImageJ

Tags: imagej

I want to measure the area of a group of clumped cells with blurred margins. I cannot set a threshold and measure the ROIs as the edges are not clear. I have to manually select the ROIs. I would then like to color in the ROIs of same area with one color so that it is easy for visualization. I want to show that that in my tissue sample there are cells of different sizes.

Please suggest how I can fill the ROIs with the same area with a color. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a macro called [ROI Color Coder](http://imagejdocu.tudor.lu/doku.php?id=macro:roi_color_coder) that colors measured ROIs according to size.  That might be close to what you want.

The easiest way to add it to ImageJ is to use the [Fiji](http://imagej.net/Fiji/Downloads) distribution of ImageJ and activate the "BAR" [update site](http://imagej.net/How_to_follow_a_3rd_party_update_site). That way you get any updates automatically.

Check out the [ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net) too -- it's a good place to get answers about using ImageJ.

Hope this helps.